# RapidMiner Multiple Filters in sequence

Tags: rapidminer

I am new to RapidMiner...What I am trying to do is that I have a list of 10 Documents which I tokenize using the ProcessDocuments Operator (subtask)-> Tokenize...the result is an **10 by 800** exampleset with 10 rows (one for each document) and 800 attributes (one for each token).

Now I want to filterbylength the 800 tokens,  I again use the ProcessDocuments Operator (subtask)-> FilterByLength **on the worldlist generated by the previous ProcessDocuments operator**...the result is a 800 by 700 matrix...800 for the 800 tokens from the previous ProcessDocuments Operator and 700 the reduced set of tokens.

What I want to accomplish is a **10 by 700 exampleset** which i can pass to the Kmeans clustering operator. How can I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using two "Process Documents" operator, since you can add the "Tokenize" and "Filter Tokens (By Length)" inside the first operator which should yield what you need.

Here is a small example for this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.005">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.005" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="text:create_document" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Create Document" width="90" x="45" y="75">
        <parameter key="text" value="This is a test with a looooooooooong word"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="text:create_document" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Create Document (2)" width="90" x="45" y="165">
        <parameter key="text" value="Again a text which has anoooooooooooooother long word."/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="text:process_documents" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="112" name="Process Documents" width="90" x="313" y="75">
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="text:tokenize" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Tokenize" width="90" x="45" y="30"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="text:filter_by_length" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="60" name="Filter Tokens (by Length)" width="90" x="179" y="30">
            <parameter key="max_chars" value="10"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="document" to_op="Tokenize" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Tokenize" from_port="document" to_op="Filter Tokens (by Length)" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Filter Tokens (by Length)" from_port="document" to_port="document 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_document" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="k_means" compatibility="5.3.005" expanded="true" height="76" name="Clustering" width="90" x="447" y="75"/>
      <connect from_op="Create Document" from_port="output" to_op="Process Documents" to_port="documents 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Create Document (2)" from_port="output" to_op="Process Documents" to_port="documents 2"/>
      <connect from_op="Process Documents" from_port="example set" to_op="Clustering" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Clustering" from_port="cluster model" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Comment: hi maerch, thats how I have done it, but I just asked to know if the way I proposed it was possible or not i.e my using two process documents....

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with the answer provided already; it looks like it solves the problem however you could do something like the following.

- Convert the 800 word list to an example set using the WordList to Data operator.
- Change the type of the polynominal word attribute to text using the Nominal to Text operator.
- Use the Process Documents from Data operator on the text attributes and filter by length inside this.

I made something vaguely similar [here](http://rapidminernotes.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/finding-needles-in-text-haystacks.html)

The 700 word limit would be hard to control. It seems to me that it would be very unlikely that a list of words sorted by length would have a convenient cut-off at 700.